# How can I construct a regular expression to account for non-consecutive characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm currently using this regex for my names `\A^[a-zA-Z'.,\s-]*\z`; however, I don't want there to be any consecutive characters for a apostrophe, period, comma, whitespace, or hyphen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The significant part would be `(?:[a-zA-Z]|['.,\s-](?!['.,\s-]))`.

Meaning:

```
(?:
    [a-zA-Z]         # letters
|                    # or
    ['.,\s-]         # any of these
    (?!['.,\s-])     # but in front can not be another of these
)
```

But, in this case:

```
Guedes, Washington
------^^----------
```

Would invalidate the name, so maybe you want remove `\s` from the negative look-ahead.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the requirements. Or I did. :)

Comment: I'm only trying to match one name at a time, first, last, middle, etc.  Perhaps the comma isn't needed even though I included it originally.

Comment: I altered it just a bit thanks for the great explanation also! `\A(?:[a-zA-Z]|['.,\s-](?!['.,\s-]))*\z`

Answer (score 1):

How about this (string of letters, potentially ending with one of those terminator chars)

```
\A^[a-zA-Z]*['.,\s-]?\z
```

Comment: This won't match to `D'Angelo` for instance.

Comment: @daveomcd: Well, fix your requirements then :)

Comment: perhaps there is confusion when I say consecutive characters, I'm saying only consecutive characters for the non a-z characters.

Comment: In "D'Angelo", 'A' is consecutive to the apostrophe, so this should not match

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear, thanks for taking the time to assist!